# MySQL: Normalizing content types, categories, and subcategories

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-normalization

I have the following basic table structure

- **Content**

  - id
  - type_id *(FK to ContentType)*
  - category_id *(nullable FK to Category)*
  - sub_category_id *(nullable FK to SubCategory)*
- **ContentType**

  - id
- **Category**

  - id
  - content_type_id *(FK to ContentType)*
- **SubCategory**

  - id
  - category_id *(FK to Category)*

It is important that the content's category should match its type.

Similarly the content's subcategory should match its category.

I'm aware that currently this is wide open to mismatching data. For example, a content record may have a category not allowed by its type and a subcategory not allowed by its category.

How could I change the table structure to secure against this? Or should I stick to using application logic?

**SCHEMA BY REQUEST**

```
CREATE TABLE `content_type` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `category` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content_type_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_category_content_type` FOREIGN KEY (`content_type_id`) REFERENCES `content_type` (`id`),
)

CREATE TABLE `sub_category` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_sub_category_category` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`),
)

CREATE TABLE `content` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `sub_category_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_content_type` FOREIGN KEY (`type_id`) REFERENCES `content_type` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_content_category` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `category` (`id`)
  CONSTRAINT `fk_content_sub_category` FOREIGN KEY (`sub_category_id`) REFERENCES `sub_category` (`id`)
)
```

Comment: First note, if you have sub-categories, you should be linking them to their parent, so in the sub-categories table you should add a field for the parent category. Second note, it is not clear what you mean by **normalizing**.

Comment: As per using application logic, this is what Stored Procedures/Functions are made for.

Comment: @FDavidov not sure what you mean.. there is a field category_id for the parent category in SubCategory.

Comment: Attempt the use of FK constraints. If they choke, it may be an indication of problems. Seek compliance via DB enforcement, not faulty app logic, first.

Comment: If category_id in subcategories is aimed to store the **parent**, I would suggest naming it accordingly. As for Foreign Keys (@Drew's suggestion), this would perhaps be the first time I would disagree with him (in my experience, FK should be used only when there is no other reasonable option).

Comment: A sign of a good db design @FDavidov is over use of FK's

Comment: @Drew I have updated to show the FKs that are already in place.

Comment: why don't you do a `show create table xyz` for each xyz. Human typed bullet points are at best weak

Comment: @FDavidov, sub_category is the sub_category of a category, calling a non-self-referencing field parent is more confusing than an id to the table it references. As for 'FK should be used only when there is no other reasonable option'... madness!

Comment: Arth, you should consider @Drew's suggestion (though I disagree with him, his opinions are always worth considering).

Comment: @Drew because all the other information is superfluous, so I figured it was easier to see the relationships this way.

Comment: The last time I checked, the db engine uses text pumped to it, not this way or fancy 1MB png's people often produce :p

Comment: Btw NULLable FK means "I might be somewhat serious about an FK, but when I am not serious, I will NULL it"

Comment: @Drew, but I'm not asking a DB engine.. Does it? It just means that a content record might not have a category or subcategory in this case.

Comment: Garbage in garbage out. Just don't think that your db has clean data just because you have a non-enforceable constraint. It is like a sign saying "Must be 21" and letting teenagers in

Comment: @Drew, That's pretty much why I'm asking the question! Hmm, is it!? If the content record has a sub category it must be in the sub category table, otherwise it has no (null) sub category.. I suppose I could do a HAS_ONE relationship instead.

Comment: @Drew Besides, even if I remove the nullable, I have the same problem!

Comment: We are 25 minutes in, still no schema. I am off looking at other stuff, which I was anyway :p

Comment: @Drew, Yeah right, because this is soooo hard to understand... fine I'll add the schema (which will say exactly the same thing).

Comment: Expanding on @FDavidov, normalizing once meant conformance to one of the recognized normal forms (1NF through 5NF).  Nowadays, some people use it as buzzword for "good design".  It's not clear what normal form you are seeking to conform to.

Comment: A normalized design will have a lot of FKs in it, when compared to a logically equivalent less normalized design.  Normalization and FK avoidance are two conflicting design goals.

Comment: @WalterMitty I'm not sure which of the normal forms I'm after, but I wanted to prevent the data mismatch described in the question

Comment: OK, so the word "normalize" in your question title wasn't with reference to one of the recognized normal forms.  It was about constraining the data in such a way that certain mismatches simply cannot occur.  You need to make sure there is only one relationship path between any two facts stored in the database.  Your design has multiple paths.

Comment: Simple question: can a content refer to a category and not to a subcategory?

Comment: @TommCatt Yes it can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Category table, create a unique index on (id, content_type_id). In the SubCategory table, create a unique index on (id, category_id).

Then in Content table, create FKs like this:

```
constraint FK_ContentCategory foreign key( category_id, type_id )
    references Category( id, content_type_id )

constraint FK_ContentSubCategory foreign key( sub_category_id, category_id )
    references SubCategory( id, category_id )
```

The FKs in Category and SubCategory tables remain the same.

Since the subcategory depends on the category which depends on the content type, make the FK references reflect the same chain of dependency. Now once you enter a type_id in the Content table, the category and subcategory values must belong to the proper chain of dependency.

However, if you ever need to change the type of a Content entry, you must first change category_id and sub_category_id to NULL, modify type_id, then insert correct values into category_id and sub_category_id. Small price to pay for solid data integrity.

Comment: Wasn't entirely sure that the separately `NULL`able `category_id` and `subcategory_id` would play nice across these two overlapping composite FKs.. so ended up creating two more HAS_ONE tables `content_category (content_id, content_type_id, category_id)` and `content_sub_category (content_id, category_id, sub_category_id)`.. where there was no issue with `NULL` and similar FKs. As the basic idea was from your answer and it would work great without the `NULL`s  I will accept! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you can only add basic constraints. There is no way you can add conditional constraints (would love to see that).

Alternatively, you could built the checks in a BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE TRIGGER. And use a SIGNAL to cancel the INSERT/UPDATE (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html)

TBH I think it could become a *true* issue if you have '3rd-party' systems talking **directly** to the database. If not, you could solve it in your app. logic, and create  API for the 3rd-party access.

If you really want to solve this on RDBMS level, you could have a look at PostgreSQL (via CHECK).

NOTE: With regard to you category tables, i would *consider* adding a parent_id and keep it in one  table (self relation). That would allow to nest your category's passed the second level.